# Is 1 hour 15 minutes enough time to move from a United Airlines flight to an Air Japan flight at Narita?

Tags: short-connections, united-airlines, nrt

My wife and I are flying into Narita Airport, Japan, on a United Airlines flight arriving at 3:30 pm from San Francisco. We're supposed to catch an Air Japan flight at 4:45 pm to Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam.

According to Narita's website, both airlines are supposed to operate from Terminal 1 South Wing (International). I understand that Narita is huge and very busy, and I have never been there.

I don't know if it matters, but I am American and my wife is not.

Is this doable, or should I try to find a later flight out of Narita?

Comment: For any other readers wondering, there actually is a charter operator called Air Japan, which is part of ANA (so unrelated to Japan Airlines) and flies NRT-SGN.

Comment: The usual question: are both flights on the same ticket, and do you have checked luggage?

Comment: @jcaron - Same ticket, probably checked luggage.

Answer (score 2):

Narita has a sterile transit area so you don’t need to go through customs and immigration if you are traveling on a single ticket and your bags were  checked through to your final destination. Then an hour is reasonable although I’m always nervous about delayed flights.

If you are traveling on two separate tickets because you used a discount ticket broker, then you may need to give yourself more time.